# Use of dplyr's rename_with() when no column matches the tidyselect any_of()

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I am struggling in using `rename_with()` with the tidyselector `any_of()` if there's no match within the latter.

See this example :

```
library(tidyvese)

iris |> 
  rename_with(.cols = any_of(contains("Length")),
              .fn = ~ifelse(str_detect(.x, "Petal"),
                      paste0(.x,  "_[petal_var]"),
                      paste0(.x, "_[sepal_var]")))
```

What it does is basically check if there's any variable that contains the string `"Length"`, and then it applies a function according to whether the variable contains the string `"Petal"` :

- Yes : then rename with a `"_[petal_var]"` suffix
- No: then rename with a `"_[sepal_var]"` suffix

However, this works as long as there's at least one variable matching the `any_of()` call.

Let's consider this example where there's no match :

```
iris |> 
  rename_with(.cols = any_of(contains("UNMATCHED_STRING")),
              .fn = ~ifelse(str_detect(.x, "Petal"),
                      paste0(.x,  "_[petal_var]"),
                      paste0(.x, "_[sepal_var]")))
```

This returns :

```
Error in `rename_with()`:
! `.fn` must return a character vector, not an empty logical vector.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I understand the issue : there's nothing to pass to the `.fn` argument, since no variable matches the tidyselect `.col` step.

Unfortunately I see no workaround using `rename_with()` (which is strongly desired here). In my more complex case, I need to pass fairly complex renaming functions to different datasets which may contain or not the value of `any_of(contains(...))`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the discussion of this Issue see: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6688

The simplest work around is to set the parameter `paste0(recycle0 = TRUE)`. So in your case this should work:

```
iris |> 
  rename_with(.cols = any_of(contains("UNMATCHED_STRING")),
              .fn = ~ifelse(str_detect(.x, "Petal"),
                      paste0(.x,  "_[petal_var]", recycle0 = TRUE),
                      paste0(.x, "_[sepal_var]", recycle0 = TRUE)))
```

The dplyr package maintainers have included an example to the `rename_with` man page to adress this issue.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO.  It's a general solution, and only requires the slightest modification to the `paste0` function.  (Still can't work out what `recycle0 = TRUE` is actually doing, but can confirm this works.)

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could do is using an `if/else` statement:

```r
if(any(grepl("Length", colnames(iris)))){
  iris <- 
    iris |>
    rename_with(.cols = everything(),
                .fn = ~ ifelse(str_detect(.x, "Petal"),
                               paste0(.x,  "_[petal_var]"),
                               paste0(.x, "_[sepal_var]")))
  iris
} else iris
```

Comment: This answer works in this very specific case, so thank you ! However it is not very elegant and I was looking for a simpler option inside the call to `rename_with()` so `.fn` is ignored if there's no match. If nothing more appropriate is brought, I'll validate this !

Comment: I agree, although i cannot think of another way. `any_of` is a quite ambiguous function to me